# Where clause to select a maximum of two records for every ID

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a phone numbers table that contains 5 different kinds of phone numbers. Every phone number type is identified by ID. Every user can have multiple phone numbers of any of these kinds.

I need to limit the number of phone numbers to 2 numbers max for every user ID and pull all of the phone numbers that have the `phonetype` of 1 or type 2.

So the end result should contain a result set with phone number of type 1 or 2 ONLY and have a maximum of two phone numbers for every user.

```
SELECT * FROM phone_nums
WHERE phonetype = 1 OR phonetype = 2 
ORDER BY contid
HAVING MAX(count(id)) = 2
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to do this,

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note that your AND condition `phonetype = 1 AND phonetype = 2` means you will never get a result.  Should use OR

Comment: LOL you're absolutely correct, that was a type from modifying my actual query for this question, it was `!= AND !=`, so it made sense ;) Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Maybe the LIMIT clause can solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write a performing and correct query for this question. This is one possibility that solves your problem I think:

Sample data:

```
create table phonenumbers
( person_id  number
, phone_id   number
, the_number varchar2(240)
, phonetype  number
)

insert into phonenumbers values ( 1, 1, 'first num', 1 )

insert into phonenumbers values ( 1, 2, 'second num', 1 )

insert into phonenumbers values ( 2, 3, 'third num', 1 )

insert into phonenumbers values ( 2, 4, 'fourth num', 1 )

insert into phonenumbers values ( 2, 5, 'fifth num', 1 )
select *
from   phonenumbers
where  (person_id, phone_id)
       in
       ( select person_id
         ,      min(phone_id)
         from   phonenumbers
         where  phonetype in (1, 2)
         group
         by     person_id 
         union all
         select person_id
         ,      max(phone_id)
         from   phonenumbers
         where  phonetype in (1, 2)
         group
         by     person_id
       )
```

Result:

```
1    1    first num    1
1    2    second num   1
2    3    third num    1
2    5    fifth num    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My table contains 100k+ records and it takes an extremely long time to run this query when setting the LIMIT to only 100 records (about 5 minutes), so unfortunately this isn't a possible solution for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ok, that is really long for such a data volume. With or without limit 100. I have to give up, I don't know what is causing the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get two phone numbers per user is to put them on one row and use `min()` and `max()`:

```
SELECT pn.user_id, min(phone_num) as phone1, max(phone_num) as phone2
FROM phone_nums pn
WHERE phonetype = 1 OR phonetype = 2 
GROUP BY pn.user_id;
```